# SharePoint 2013 REST-API: Reliable way to retrieve all field values of a list item?

Tags: 2013, rest, list-item, sharepoint-fields

I am trying to retrieve all field values of a specific list item via the REST-API of SharePoint 2013. The values will be used for further processing. The goal is to retrieve **all** field values dynamically, so manually specifying the required fields is out of the question. The requests are done from a Java-Applikation, so I am building the HTTP-Requests myself and not with CSOM or JSOM.

I tried the following ideas, but without satisfying results:

Simple request to `/_api/web/lists(guid)/items(id)/FieldValuesAsText`.
The problem with this approach is, that all values are returned as Strings, so I don't get typed values from the JSON parser. Also some values like dates are formatted, e.g. "8/8/2014 3:31 PM", which is not usable, as I need dates in ISO-8601 format.

My second approach was to first do a select to retrieve all available fields with `/_api/web/lists(guid)/items(id)/ParentList/Fields` and then build a select on the list item, based on the EntityPropertyName of each field. This would result in something like `/_api/web/lists(guid)/items(id)?$select=Id,Created,Author,...`. Problem is, that for example a query with `$select=Author` does not work, as Author needs to be specified in the $expand-Parameter.

Error:

> The query to field 'Author' is not valid. The $select query string
>   must specify the target fields and the $expand query string must
>   contains Author.

And I could not find a way to determine which fields have to be expanded and which not.

My third approach was similar to number two, but retrieve each field from the list item with a separate request: `/_api/web/lists(guid)/items(id)/Author`. With this I can also retrieve expanded field values as objects and don't have to deal with an $expand-Parameter in the select. The Problem with this method is that it is very slow as there are approximately 60 requests executed for just a single list item.

Does anyone know another method the retrieve all field values of a list item?

Comment: `Object.keys()` will get you all the keys in the JSON object, but will include stuff like `__metadata`, and other fields you may not be interested in.  But you can use that to loop through them all.

Answer (score 14):

How about a simple query:

```
 /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items(<item id>)
```

which will return all the field values for a list item with some limitation for User/Lookup fields:

- only lookup id values will be retrieved.

In order to request all the field values including User/Lookup field values, you could specify `*` to select all the fields plus to specify projected fields explicitly:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items(<item id>)?$select=<projected field>/Id,<projected field>/Title,*&$expand=<projected field>
```

For exampe; in order to request all the field values including projected fields (like Author and Editor user fields) the following query could be used:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<list title>')/items(<item id>)?$select=Author/Id,Author/Title,Editor/Id,Editor/Title,*&$expand=Author,Editor
```

Comment: Ok, I did try the select with a star ($select=*), but it doesn't do anything for me, I get the exact same fields as when I don't specify a $select. I could actually live with specifying every field in the $select (my second approach). But as I have to support (theoretically) every possible configuration, how can I determine the fields to expand? Are only User-Fields expandable?

Comment: User and lookup field values are expandable at least. Regarding $select=*, it indeed returns all the field values but it could be useful when you construct the query to return all the field values plus projected field values

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question but I can shed some light on one part of it.  You say that

> I could not find a way to determine which fields have to be expanded and which not.

In the schema returned by the `fields` REST endpoint, there is a value `FieldTypeKind` that tells you the type of each list.  The value is an integer from [this enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee540543(v=office.15)) and from my own experiments I think the only two that belong in `$expand` are `Lookup = 7` and `User = 20`.  Basically, if you have a field definition `{Title: "Author", FieldTypeKind: 20, EntityPropertyName: "Author", LookupField: "Title"}`, that tells you that your REST query should be `$select=Author/Title,$expand=Author`.

This gets more complex with "additional" lookup columns, where you add a column (let's call it "Category") and configure it to show the "Title" field of the lookup table, but also check the box under "Add a column to show each of these additional fields", for the column "Color".  Now you have a `{Title: "Category", FieldTypeKind: 7, EntityPropertyName: "Category", LookupField: "Title"}`, but you also have a second field definition `{Title: "Category:Color", FieldTypeKind: 7, EntityPropertyName: "Category_x005c_Color", LookupField: "Color", PrimaryFieldId: "{some guid}"}`.  You have to use the PrimaryFieldId of the additional field to find the primary field, and use its EntityPropertyName to construct the `select/expand` arguments: `$select=*,Category/Title,Category/Color,$expand=Category`.